# calling method via highchart-angular template

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement Bellcurve chart component (app\shared\highcharts\bellcurve) using Highcharts-Angular wrapper in angular 4 application. Previously i was using angular2-highcharts wrapper that had the load constuct which called the getinstance method that accepted $event.context. You could see in the bellcurvecomponent code like (load)="getInstance($event.context). How do I achieve the same using the Highcharts-angular wrapper. I have created a stackblitz example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k85q94

Currently the getinstance method isnt being called. I checked the https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular but couldnt get direction. Could somebody let me know. I tried using callbackfunction sonstruct instead of load but was throwing error and not working.

Comment: Please describe what do you need chart instance for and where in code would you like to use it.

Comment: Hi Kamil, sorry we can close this as the issue has already been resolved. The solution is using callbackfunction and assigning (this) meaning chartinstance to the getinstance method